# How to add description of application on accessibility service toggle in settings

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

working on an android application that requires user to enable that application in accessibility services
but in settings -> accessibility 
I am unable to provide description of why this application reads your personal stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use `android:description`:

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:packageNames="com.example.android.apis"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
...
/>
```

You can learn more about accessibility services and the allowed XML attributes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html).

Comment: idk as  im a noob in android development so can you please provide a more descriptive version of your answer

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work or you need more info/help @utkarshjha.